# React useEffect hook dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning about the `React` `useEffect` hook, especially the `dependency array`. Having such simple [counter](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-kov0e?file=/src/index.js:0-656):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, []); // Only re-run the effect if count changes!?

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>You clicked {count} times!</h2>

      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Decrement</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Even if the `dependency array` is empty the counter still works - the counter value is still increased/decreased when I click the button.

As far as I understand from the doc, setting the `dependency array` empty should just disable the `useEffect` to run if the dependency array doesn't explicitly list/include the changing value.

Comment: even if you provide dependency array it will still trigger on mount of component (first render)

Comment: FYI this what this specific useEffect does is updating title of your page (tab name)

Comment: React component state is independent of any `useEffect` hooks. Your question is unclear. Are you asking why the state still updates in spite of a mounting `useEffect` hook that updated the document title?

Comment: @Wraithy "even if you provide dependency array it will still trigger on mount of component (first render)" - yeah, ok BUT it'll  trigger **always** when the button is clicked , not only on the first render!

Comment: @Drew Reese I'm asking why does the `useEffect` is run if it's dependency array is empty!?(do not include the `count` variable)

Comment: The `useEffect` hook callback is guaranteed to run at least once, on component mount. The dependency array is for changes to dependency values on subsequent renders.

Comment: @DrewReese So I'm asking AGAIN why does the `useEffect` is run on subsequent renders when i click the button while the counter value ISN'T present on the  dependency values array!?

Comment: I don't believe it is. It has an empty dependency array so it runs only once on component mount. Again... your question is unclear. Are you asking why state updates independently of the `useEffect` running once on component mount? Could you perhaps describe in more detail any perceived issue? Try a `console.log(\`You clicked ${count} times\`)` in the `useEffect` hook callback and you'll see a single `"You clicked 0 times"` log.

Comment: @DrewReese. Ok, placing `console.log(`You clicked ${count} times`)` in the `useEffect` hook callback has revealed that indeed the hook is called only once when the dependency array is empty. So now my question is why does the doc title is still changing on button click even if the `useEffect` hook ISN'T called/runned on  subsequent renders!?

Comment: I don't see that behavior. https://kov0e.csb.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `useEffect` hook runs only once in component life cycle as far as you understand it unless you specify something in dependency array. Now for your question that why the counter is still updating that is because you are using `useState` which is hook responsible for updating the value in screen and has nothing to do with useEffect hook
And to make sure console.log("i run only once") in useEffect hook and you will see that it runs only one time and counter value also doesn't get increased or decreased

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` either runs on every render (if you do not use a dependency array) or once every time the dependency array changes.

On first render, the dependency array *always* changes from "no prior call" to "this is my dependency array" - `useEffect` will always be executed on the first render. If your dependency array is empty it will just not be executed any more after that.